# Facebook single sign on in iOS issue

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on, facebook-ios-sdk

I just run the demo app for the single sign on Facebook and I am getting the following:

[image]

And what I want is actually something like this:

[image]

I wanted it to not show as a web view, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see my answer here (which answers this question):

[FaceBook API, login in-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969680/facebook-api-login-in-app/6969844#6969844)

Please also note my caveat.  OAuth was designed to authenticate outside of your application - but in this case, you can make it work inside (but it breaks a core principle of OAuth).

Comment: you said that using this method the user credentials won't be remembered, what does this imply? Also why is it that all other apps do the in app authentication?

Comment: I think the user credentials would be remembered - if you implement the saving of the access token in the fbDidLogin method (which I realize is contrary to what I said in the other post).  For the other item - Facebook has made it clear that the preferred way is to do OAuth outside of the application.  I doubt they will drop support for the in-app login in the future, but it's always a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

When an app requests authorization or login, the application gets the user's login information via the browser (as you showed in the second image) or, if you have the Facebook app installed, from the Facebook app. It looks like you have the Facebook app installed, so the app automatically pulled the user's information from that app.

Then, for any new app that a user uses, Facebook verifies with the user that the app's requested features are allowed by the user.

Since your device pulled the login info from the Facebook app, the email/password screen is not used and the permissions screen is shown first. Once you allow the features, you should not see that screen again, when you start the app again for that same user.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Facebook.m

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions {
  self.permissions = permissions;

  // with both options NO, authorization always happens in-app
  [self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:NO safariAuth:NO];
}
```